# How to enable ssh key authentication for root users?

Tags: ssh, unix, centos

I want root user to be able to login via ssh key authentication. How can I get that done? I tried changing the ssh config file and adding PermitRootLogin without-password but that didn't work. I also tried reload sshd. I'm using centos 6.

Comment: what do you see in the server error log (`/var/log/secure`)? Did you restart your `sshd` service?

Comment: Besides setting PermitRootLogin to yes and restarting sshd, you copied your public key into /root/.sshd/authorized_keys (which has rights 600), didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have done everything right (as per comments above), and it still doesn't work - the problem (and I hit it regularly) relates to SELinux rules.

You can check that this is the case by [ temporarily ? ] disabling SELinux by "echo 0 > /selinux/enforcing" and see if things start working.

Apparently the [solution](http://www.firedaemon.com/blog/passwordless-root-ssh-public-key-authentication-on-centos-6) would be to log in to the box and run "restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh"  (I confess to not doing it this way, I just used corepolicyutils and made a ssh.pe file which I copy and load on each system which has this problem).